# Prove that a symmetric filter preserve an p-order trend

Tags: filter

Let the centered filter

$\Theta (L)=\theta _{-m}L^m+...+\theta _{-2}L^2+\theta _{-1}L+\theta _{0}+\theta _{1}L^{-1}+\theta _{2}L^{-2}+...+\theta _{m}L^{-m}$

where $\theta _{-m}+...\theta _{-2}+\theta _{-1}+\theta _{0}+\theta _{1}+\theta _{2}+...+\theta _{m}=1$.

Under what conditions this filter preserves a p-order trend, that is $\Theta (L)t^p=t^p$?

So, applying the definition of the filter, we have
$\Theta (L)t^p=(\theta _{-m}L^m+...+\theta _{-2}L^2+\theta _{-1}L+\theta _{0}+\theta _{1}L^{-1}+\theta _{2}L^{-2}+...+\theta _{m}L^{-m})t^p$
$\Theta (L)t^p=\theta _{-m}(t-m)^p+...+\theta _{-2}(t-2)^p+\theta _{-1}(t-1)^p+\theta _{0}t^p+\theta _{1}(t+1)^p+\theta _{2}(t+2)^p+...+\theta _{m}(t+m)^p$

Since the filter is symmetric

$\Theta (L)t^p=\theta _{m}((t-m)^p+(t+m)^p)+...+\theta _{-2}((t-2)^p+(t+2)^p)+\theta _{-1}((t-1)^p+(t+1)^p)+\theta _{0}t^p$

Here I'm stuck. Anyone could give me a hand?

Comment: Hint: you only need to examine the coefficient of $t^p$ itself: there are no higher powers present and you don't care about the lower powers.  That coefficient is easily computed in terms of the sum of the $\theta_i$.  Because the answer turns out to be rather uninteresting, I wonder whether your assumption shouldn't be that the sum of *absolute values* of the $\theta_i$ is unity?